# Search paginate laravel result

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

```
public function cari_user_status(Request $request)
{       
    $users = User::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);

    if ( ! empty($request->nama))
    {
        $users = $users->where('name', $request->nama)->paginate();
    }

    return view('users.index',  compact('users'));        
}
```

I have a search function in my controller but it isn't working.

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not
>   exist.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$users = User::latest()
    ->when( ! empty($request->get('name')), function ($query) use ($request) {
        return $query->whereRaw("UPPER(name) LIKE '%" . strtoupper($request->get('name')) . "%'");
    })
    ->paginate(10);

return view('users.index', [
    'users' => $users,
]);
```

Also you have a typo in your "$request->nama"

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the error because you are applying a filter on the paginated result i.e.

```
$users = User::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
if ( ! empty($request->nama))
{
    // Problem is here $users is a collection of paginated result
    $users = $users->where('name', $request->nama)->paginate();
}
```

Try like this.

```
public function cari_user_status(Request $request)
{       
    $users = (new User())->query(); 

    if ( ! empty($request->nama))
    {
        $users->where('name', $request->nama);
    }

    $users = $users->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);

    return view('users.index',  compact('users'));        
}
```